# How can I add a ResourceDictionary defined in a subfolder to App.xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, app.xaml

All of the code samples I've found so far reference a Resource Dictionary that's not in a project subfolder (the dictionary is at the root of the project). I have mine in a subfolder, and I can't figure out how to get WPF to find it. This doesn't work...

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/Black/GlossyButtons.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

The ASP.Net tilde syntax doesn't seem to work either.

Is this the best way to include a ResourceDictionary in your app so that WPF can find resources? My goal in this particular case is to apply a style defined in GlossyButtons.xaml to all of the buttons in my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovered the problem - WPF couldn't find an assembly referenced in GlossyButtons.xaml, but didn't show  the actual error (that there was a problem with the .xaml) until I had compiled and executed several times. The error displayed (at first) was that GlossyButtons.xaml couldn't be located.

That was a little confusing.

Answer (score 6):

Try the Pack URI syntax

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Skins/Black/GlossyButtons.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I found a few references to that syntax online, but I was able to get it working with just a relative path, like so ...<ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/Black/GlossyButtons.xaml"/>. I'm compiling against .Net 4.0 - maybe relative path support is a new feature?